# Count all MySQL tables with similar column name

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure that should execute the sample code:

```html
IF EXISTS (
               SELECT TABLE_NAME
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TB1', 'TB2', 'TB3')
               AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL'
              AND table_schema = 'TestDB' 
                  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
                  HAVING count (TABLE_NAME) = 3
               )  
                THEN
                   /*Used for debugging*/ 
                    SELECT 'Tables EXIST' INTO msg;  
                ELSE
                   /*Used for debugging*/   
                    SELECT 'NON-EXISTENT TABLES !' INTO msg; 
                END IF
​
```

Basically, I want the above snippet to select all specified tables that has a column named 'COL'. I only want to do this using information_schema, nothing else.

Upon check, the test statement (IF EXISTS) always returned false. That is, the ELSE statement always execute even though my three test tables (TB1, TB2 and TB3) have the COL field. What sin am I commiting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as a function like this:

Function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `new_function`() RETURNS varchar(64) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    declare cnt int;

    declare msg varchar(64);

    select count(*) from (
    select distinct
        table_name
    from information_schema.columns
        where table_name in ('TB1', 'TB2', 'TB3')
        and column_name = 'COL'
        and table_schema = 'TestDB'
    ) tbls into cnt;

    if cnt = 3 then
        select 'tables exist' into msg;
    else
        select 'tables do not exists' into msg;
    end if;

RETURN msg;
END
```

And then run this:

```
create schema TestDB;

use TestDB;

create table TB1(
    COL int
);

create table TB2(
    COL int
);

create table TB3(
    COL int
);    

select new_function();
```

This will return:
Tables Exist

Answer (score 0):

Something parallel to this should work

```
select distinct 
    table_name 
from information_schema.columns
    where column_name = 'CHARACTER_SET_NAME'
    and table_name in ('CHARACTER_SETS', 'COLLATIONS', 'COLUMNS', 'TRIGGERS', 'FOO', 'BAR')
;
```

where you have this

```
       SELECT TABLE_NAME
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
       WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('TB1', 'TB2', 'TB3')
       AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL'
       AND table_schema = 'TestDB' 
          GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
          HAVING count (TABLE_NAME) = 3
       )
```

i.e. this:

```
select distinct
    table_name
from information.schema.columns
    where table_name in ('TB1', 'TB2', 'TB3')
    and column_name = 'COL'
    and table_schema = 'TestDB'
```

and if you want to make sure all three tables exist and have a 'COL' column write a conditional to check that this evaluates to 3

```
select count(*) from (
select distinct
    table_name
from information.schema.columns
    where table_name in ('TB1', 'TB2', 'TB3')
    and column_name = 'COL'
    and table_schema = 'TestDB'
) tbls
;
```

Comment: thanks. but i dont seem to understand your code. i posted this for educational pupose. to be clear, say i have tables A, B and C. i want a query that will return 2 if only two of the tables have COL in common, false otherwise.